# There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue. (Bundler::GemfileError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, passenger, redmine

I cannot access my Redmine application.
Bundler version 1.7.4 (I've already checked downgrade to earlier versions, but nothing changed then)
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

Phusion Passenger show below error:

```
There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue. (Bundler::GemfileError)
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/dsl.rb:12:in `rescue in evaluate'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/dsl.rb:6:in `evaluate'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:18:in `build'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:135:in `definition'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:123:in `load'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:245:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:348:in `running_bundler'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:243:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.40/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.40/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.40/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.40/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

and here's the Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "rails", "3.2.17"
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 2.0.2"
gem "coderay", "~> 1.1.0"
gem "fastercsv", "~> 1.5.0", :platforms => [:mri_18, :mingw_18, :jruby]
gem "builder", "3.0.0"
gem "mime-types"
gem "awesome_nested_set", "2.1.6"

# Optional gem for LDAP authentication
group :ldap do
  gem "net-ldap", "~> 0.3.1"
end

# Optional gem for OpenID authentication
group :openid do
  gem "ruby-openid", "~> 2.3.0", :require => "openid"
  gem "rack-openid"
end

platforms :mri, :mingw do
  # Optional gem for exporting the gantt to a PNG file, not supported with jruby
  group :rmagick do
    # RMagick 2 supports ruby 1.9
    # RMagick 1 would be fine for ruby 1.8 but Bundler does not support
    # different requirements for the same gem on different platforms
    gem "rmagick", ">= 2.0.0"
  end

  # Optional Markdown support, not for JRuby
  group :markdown do
    # TODO: upgrade to redcarpet 3.x when ruby1.8 support is dropped
    gem "redcarpet", "~> 2.3.0"
  end
end

platforms :jruby do
  # jruby-openssl is bundled with JRuby 1.7.0
  gem "jruby-openssl" if Object.const_defined?(:JRUBY_VERSION) && JRUBY_VERSION < '1.7.0'
  gem "activerecord-jdbc-adapter", "~> 1.3.2"
end

# Include database gems for the adapters found in the database
# configuration file
require 'erb'
require 'yaml'
database_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "config/database.yml")
if File.exist?(database_file)
  database_config = YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read(database_file)).result)
  adapters = database_config.values.map {|c| c['adapter']}.compact.uniq
  if adapters.any?
    adapters.each do |adapter|
      case adapter
      when 'mysql2'
        gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.11", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]
        gem "activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby
      when 'mysql'
        gem "mysql", "~> 2.8.1", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]
        gem "activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby
      when /postgresql/
        gem "pg", ">= 0.11.0", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]
        gem "activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby
      when /sqlite3/
        gem "sqlite3", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]
        gem "activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter", :platforms => :jruby
      when /sqlserver/
        gem "tiny_tds", "~> 0.5.1", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]
        gem "activerecord-sqlserver-adapter", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]
      else
        warn("Unknown database adapter `#{adapter}` found in config/database.yml, use Gemfile.local to load your own database gems")
      end
    end
  else
    warn("No adapter found in config/database.yml, please configure it first")
  end
else
  warn("Please configure your config/database.yml first")
end

group :development do
  gem "rdoc", ">= 2.4.2"
  gem "yard"
end

group :test do
  gem "shoulda", "~> 3.3.2"
  gem "mocha", ">= 0.14", :require => 'mocha/api'
  if RUBY_VERSION >= '1.9.3'
    gem "capybara", "~> 2.1.0"
    gem "selenium-webdriver"
  end
end

local_gemfile = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "Gemfile.local")
if File.exists?(local_gemfile)
  puts "Loading Gemfile.local ..." if $DEBUG # `ruby -d` or `bundle -v`
  instance_eval File.read(local_gemfile)
end

# Load plugins' Gemfiles
Dir.glob File.expand_path("../plugins/*/Gemfile", __FILE__) do |file|
  puts "Loading #{file} ..." if $DEBUG # `ruby -d` or `bundle -v`
  #TODO: switch to "eval_gemfile file" when bundler >= 1.2.0 will be required (rails 4)
  instance_eval File.read(file), file
end
```

Any suggestions very appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
King regards

Comment: Either your `Gemfile.local` or a `Gemfile` in one of your plugins has invalid syntax. You could try to gradually remove all of them to identify the culprit. Then you can fix it (e.g. by removing the erroneous plugin)

Comment: If you run `bundle` locally it should show you the specific error that is occurring.